# Most elegant way to update data from a user POST in a SessionScoped bean (CDI, JSF)

Tags: jsf, cdi

I have a SessionScoped CDI-bean holding user data.

```
@SessionScoped
public class UserData {
  private String name;
  private String city;
  .. several other attributes
}
```

The user wants to update his data in a form (JSF). Therefore I use a "FrontendModel" to encapsulate all the attributes.

## FrontendModel

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class UserDataFrontendModel {
  private String name;
  private String city;
  .. several other attributes
}
```

## JSF-Page:

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{userDataFrontendModel.name}"/>
<h:inputText id="city" value="#{userDataFrontendModel.city}"/>
```

## Controller

```
@RequestScoped
@Named
public class UserDataController {

  @Inject
  private UserDataFrontendModel userDataFrontendModel;

  @Inject
  private UserData userData;

  public String updateUserData() {
      userData.setName(userDataFrontendModel.getName());
      userData.setCity(userDataFrontendModel.getCity());
      return null;
  }

@PostConstruct
private void initUserDataFrontendModel() {
  if(isUpdate) {
     userDataFrontendModel.setName(userData.getName());
     userDataFrontendModel.setCity(userData.getCity());
  }
}
```

Is this overengineered?! I don't want to have all the user's properties directly in the controller. Should UserDataFrontendBean be a CDI-bean? Is there a simpler way to do what I want? I can't directly use my UserData object, can I?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have the `UserDataController` declared as `@Named @SessionScoped` and just have the `UserData` field there. Since `UserDataController` will be stored in session scope, all its fields will be in session scope as well. Using this approach, you don't need the `UserDataFrontendModel` class at all.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class UserDataController {
    @Inject
    private UserData userData;
    @PostConstruct
    private void initUserDataFrontendModel() {
        userData = new UserData();
    }
    public void updateUserData() {
         //logic to update the data in database or something
    }
}
```

Then just bind the data from `UserData` directly to your elements in view:

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{userDataController.userData.name}" />
    <h:inputText value="#{userDataController.userData.city}" />
    <h:commandButton value="Update User Data"
        action="#{userDataController.updateUserData}" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: Oh this isn't a really good approach. UserData holds the login data for the current user and is injected in several other beans. I don't want to directly let the user (or jsf via setters) set data without validation etc. 
But I think UserDataFrontendModel doesn't need to be a CDI bean. #{userDataController.userDataFrontendModel.name} is ok.

Comment: Then why do you ask this question to begin with?